# Out of Memory Error while executing JS via cl_java_script

Tags: javascript, abap

I'm executing a JS program from ABAP report, so in my JS program i'm trying to load resource using :

```
oReader.load(oResource, oDiagramDef);
```

But i'm getting `error : out of memory`

EDIT: comment added by OP: "i'm using cl_java_script from abap"

Comment: How do you launch JS from ABAP?

Comment: @Suncatcher i'm using cl_java_script from abap

Comment: Could you give a little more surrounding information/context?